# How to use rigidbody with collision gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I don't know how i can activate rigidbody is kinematic in my game because I want to get collision gameobject and his child to use gravity after collision.

I have tried this:

```
collision.rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
```

but the unity complains and give me this issue;

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Player.OnCollisionExit (UnityEngine.Collision collision) (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:258)

but when I want to try with:
collision.gameObject.rigidbody the unity can not find the rigidbody..

Please stackoverflow help me once more, 
thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The colliding object does not have a Rigidbody.

Make sure that you add conditional checks to make sure the code is only triggering when you collide with the desired object, for instance:

```
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "MyKineticObject")
{
    collision.rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
}
```

Comment: The unity complains I have check for tag but it doesn't work because i didn't put reference on a object.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand..? Maybe show with pictures?

Answer (score 0):

you should do the following code:-

```
collision.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
```

or

```
Rigidbody rb = collision.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
rb.isKinematic = false;
```